# Where to ask my non scifi/fantasy Identify-this-Movie question on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

After Movies&TV [discontinued identification questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4087/we-are-discontinuing-support-for-identification-questions), people moved to Science Fiction & Fantasy, from what I saw from the plethora of Hot Questions popping up.

Today, I want to ask a question about a non-science fiction or fantasy movie that search engines cannot find for me, but a human surely can - pretty sure folks over Movies & TV would do, but that's *not* allowed now.

SE is my last resort, is there any site for my asking to identify a movie?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't. Refer to [this post on Movies.SE meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129/63559) to find a list of external identification resources.

> First of all, there are a few sites within the StackExchange network which still accept such questions:
>
> - [**Science Fiction & Fantasy**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) obviously requires the work to contain distinct science-fiction or fantasy content. You can consult their meta on [how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/23386).
> - [**Music Fans**](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/) currently takes questions asking to identify music videos. But again, make sure you get acquainted with [what they expect from a good identification question](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/a/368/20).
>
> Then there are also some other Q&A sites working similar to SE where you can just provide a description and ask for a movie:
>
> - [**I Remember This Movie...**](https://irememberthismovie.com/)
>
>   - [**NameThatMovie?**](http://namethatmovie.org/)
>   - [**Filmfind**](https://filmfind.co/)
>   - [**Reddit's /r/tipofmytongue**](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/) (be sure to read the rules sidebar first!)
>   - [**What is my movie?**](https://www.whatismymovie.com/)
>   - [Criticker.com](https://www.criticker.com) has a [**Help me name that movie**](https://www.criticker.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=17&sid=401cc87387d72326bb5d62d3d377e503) forum

Comment: That said, don't hesitate to politely try [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room). Some folks living alone, on national lockdown, with no remote work available, may very much want to try and find it because they're getting bored (yes, I _am_ among those).

Comment: I wouldn't like to invest in creating another account in another site, I love SE, and miss the old days in Movies SE. :/ Hmmm, chat? You mean that there is a char group that I could try? :)

Comment: @gsamaras Movies and TV's chat, I edited in a link above. See you there in a few moments? :)