# Where can we ask questions about film identification?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Film identification questions are off-topic on Movies & TV SE, so where can we ask them now?

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. If the film involves science fiction and/or fantasy elements then, if appropriately written, you can try at the [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) SE site. I've noticed that most of their HNQ (Hot Network Questions) posts are basically identification questions (not only of film, but also of books, TV, manga, etc.).

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4129)

Comment: You can add [your question from SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/260447/110535) to the question above (using > and quotes) to improve it here, and in addition answer your own question below (if the question there remains on-topic).

Comment: For anybody interested, a closely related question is [Where to ask my non scifi/fantasy Identify-this-Movie question on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345254/562482).

Answer (score 5):

If the film falls in the science fiction, fantasy, *supernatural* horror, or any related genre of speculative fiction, you can ask on the [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) Stack.

Please provide as thorough a description as possible, including all details you might remember, no matter how insignificant they may seem. There's [a guide on how to ask](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/19561), but the most important points are *what, when, where*. In other words, describe what you remember of the content, let us know the (approximate) year you saw it, and where that was (movie theater or tv, and where in the world).
Please tag with `[story-identification]`. Use additional tags for the medium.